# Преобразование списка массивов строк в переменную типа String

Tags: java, массивы, list, преобразование

Имеется список массивов строк:

```
List<String[]> name
```

Как его преобразовать в переменную:

```
String text = ?
```

Comment: `список массива строк list name` - а если наглядно? что еще за список массива строк? и какой язык?

Comment: язык укажите пожалуйста

Comment: java, поправил текст

Comment: проитерируйте по каждому массиву списка и склейту в строку все их члены.

Comment: Строки нужно склеить? Нужно четко указать в самом вопросе в чем заключается «преобразование». Если преобразование сложнее конкатенации, то будет полезно привести пример входных данных и ожидаемого результата.

Comment: я пытаюсь вывести содержимое csv файла в строку для лога, на входе list<String[]> на выходе String

Answer (score 3):

Вот вариант с использованием streams

```
String text = name.stream()
                  .flatMap(Stream::of)
                  .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Answer (score 1):

Зачем так вычурно, можно же в духе oldschool:

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
for(String[] ss:name) {
   for(String s:ss) {
       sb.append(s);
   }
}
String text=sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1, цикл + `String.join`

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String[] s : name){
    sb.append(String.join("", s));
}
String text = sb.toString();
```

Вариант 2, `stream` + `flatMap`

```
String text = name.stream()
                  .flatMap(Stream::of)
                  .collect(Collectors.joining())
```

Вариант 3, `stream` + `map` + `String.join`

```
String text = name.stream()
                  .map(sa -> String.join("", sa))
                  .collect(Collectors.joining())
```

Продолжать до бесконечности. На мой взгляд вариант 2 самый красивый.